# No se puede usar == en una variable de tipo string [ ]

Tags: c#, string

Estoy tratando de hacer una calculadora, pero me sale un error al ejecutar el programa.
Intenté usar entre.Equals(simb), pero la salida era el mensaje de error que puse como predeterminado.
Si no encuentro solución, planeo hacer strings con solo un valor con "entre" y "por", pero... La gracia de programar es encontrar soluciones ¿Cierto?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace Calculadora
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
          string mas = "+" ; 
          string menos = "-";
          string [] por = new string[3]{
          "x",
          "*",
          "×",
                                        };
           string [] entre = new string[2] {
             "/" ,
             "÷",
                                           }; 
                                                                    
        //-----------------------------------------------
          int num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
          string simb = Console.ReadLine();
          int num2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        //-----------------------------------------------
        if (simb == mas){
            num += num2;
            Console.Write("El resultado es: ");
            Console.Write(num);
                         }
       else if (simb == menos){
        num -= num2;
            Console.Write("El resultado es: ");
            Console.Write(num); 
                              }
        else if (simb == entre){                        //error
          num /= num2;          
            Console.Write("El resultado es: ");
            Console.Write(num);  
                               }
          else if (simb == por){                       //error
          num *= num2;
            Console.Write("El resultado es: ");
            Console.Write(num);                    
                                }
       else         {
        Console.WriteLine("Error, inserte una operacion valida. Ejemplo:");
        Console.WriteLine("2");
        Console.WriteLine("+");
        Console.WriteLine("2");
                     }

        }
    }
}
```

Al usar == en un string con un solo valor no me daba errores, pero al agregar el string "por" y "mas" no me permite usar ==.

Lamento que sea un código desordenado, lo hice con algo de prisa y soy bastante novato.

Comment: Las variables `por` y `entre` no son de tipo `string`, son de tipo `Array`, cuyo contenido es `string`. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ese error te da porque estás tratando de comparar un **arreglo de string** con un **string** y son tipos de datos diferentes, un **arreglo de string** es una colección de varios **string** y una variable de tipo **string** solamente guarda un dato único.

Para solucionar este problema te recomiendo que uses **Linq**:

```
if (por.Count(x => x == simb) > 0)
{
   //Tu código
}
else if (entre.Count(x => x == simb) > 0)
{
   //Tu código 
}
```

Aquí se usa el **operador Count** de **Linq** para contar si en los **arreglos entre** o **por** aparece el símbolo que entraste por teclado, de aparecer ese símbolo entonces el **operador Count** devolverá un número indicando la cantidad de veces que aparece ese símbolo en el arreglo indicado que en este caso ese valor sería **1**, de no aparecer el símbolo entonces **Count** retornará **0**. Si se retorna un número mayor que **0** entonces ese símbolo existe en el arreglo indicado.

Para hacer uso de **Linq** debes poner en los **usings**:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Tengo una última duda: porque está ahí el x > x? No lo acabo de entender. Ya aplique los cambios y funciona perfectamente!! Pero quiero entender el "porque" detrás de esas x. Gracias de nuevo!!!

Comment: Eso es un tema avanzado, te recomiendo que investigues en internet sobre expresiones lambda y Linq, x=>x es una expresión lambda, una especie de función